# project server 2010 provisioning doesnt finish

Tags: project-server, ms-project

I want to deploy a project server 2010 service web application (PWA) on sharepoint 2010. After all steps, in provisioning step it doesn't finish.
In 'Event Viewer' there is an event by ID: 17173 in every 2 seconds!

```
Starting up database 'ProjectServer_Published'.
```

and in detail:

```
+ System 

- Provider 

[ Name]  MSSQL$SHAREPOINT 

- EventID 17137 

[ Qualifiers]  16384 

Level 4 

Task 2 

Keywords 0x80000000000000 

- TimeCreated 

[ SystemTime]  2012-10-20T11:27:29.000000000Z 

EventRecordID 18626 

Channel Application 




- EventData 

ProjectServer_Published 
    F14200000A000000160000005300480041005200450050004F0049004E0054005C005300480041005200450050004F0049004E0054000000070000006D00610073007400650072000000 


 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words

0000: 000042F1 0000000A 00000016 00480053 
0008: 00520041 00500045 0049004F 0054004E 
0010: 0053005C 00410048 00450052 004F0050 
0018: 004E0049 00000054 00000007 0061006D 
0020: 00740073 00720065 0000  


In Bytes

0000: F1 42 00 00 0A 00 00 00   ñB......
0008: 16 00 00 00 53 00 48 00   ....S.H.
0010: 41 00 52 00 45 00 50 00   A.R.E.P.
0018: 4F 00 49 00 4E 00 54 00   O.I.N.T.
0020: 5C 00 53 00 48 00 41 00   \.S.H.A.
0028: 52 00 45 00 50 00 4F 00   R.E.P.O.
0030: 49 00 4E 00 54 00 00 00   I.N.T...
0038: 07 00 00 00 6D 00 61 00   ....m.a.
0040: 73 00 74 00 65 00 72 00   s.t.e.r.
0048: 00 00                     ..
```

And this is log file :

```
10/20/2012 15:24:16.93  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1814)    0x0E20  Project Server  General         8zd0    Medium  [SERVICE]    ProjectEventService14: Not starting ExecProcess for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f  No sites defined 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.61  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1844)    0x0AF4  Project Server  Provisioning    8zdn    Medium  [SERVICE] ProjectQueueService14: Getting list of Sites for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.61  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1844)    0x0AF4  Project Server  General         8zdb    High    [SERVICE] ProjectQueueService14: ProcessWatcher signaled    
10/20/2012 15:25:16.61  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1844)    0x0AF4  Project Server  General         8zdk    High    [SERVICE] ProjectQueueService14: ProcessWatcher restarting service for 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f PID: -1 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.61  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1844)    0x0AF4  Project Server  Provisioning    8zdn    Medium  [SERVICE] ProjectQueueService14: Getting list of Sites for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.61  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1844)    0x0AF4  Project Server  General         8zd0    Medium  [SERVICE] ProjectQueueService14: Not starting ExecProcess for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f  No sites defined    
10/20/2012 15:25:16.94  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1814)    0x0E20  Project Server  General         8zdb    High    [SERVICE] ProjectEventService14: ProcessWatcher signaled    
10/20/2012 15:25:16.94  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1814)    0x0E20  Project Server  General         8zdk    High    [SERVICE] ProjectEventService14: ProcessWatcher restarting service for 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f PID: -1 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.94  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1814)    0x0E20  Project Server  Provisioning    8zdn    Medium  [SERVICE] ProjectEventService14: Getting list of Sites for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f 
10/20/2012 15:25:16.94  Microsoft.Office.Project.Server (0x1814)    0x0E20  Project Server  General         8zd0    Medium  [SERVICE] ProjectEventService14: Not starting ExecProcess for ServiceApp: 60739e6d-8645-485a-8ef0-e8217e80c87f  No sites defined
```

What is the problem? There is neither error nor warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The cause was a bad version of MSSQL.
I reinstalled "Microsoft SQL Sever 2008 RT", and there was not any problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Try the following:
>
> 1. Stop & Start Project Application service (Ensure the Project service started too)
> 2. Ensure that the PWA web site has Service Application associations with Project server service application
> 3. If possible delete Project Server Service Application, create new one with appropriate permission
> 4. 'LINEAR\sp2010rtm'  - Add this account to local administrators group and check the status.

For more information check this link out:

[Same Problem Solved on different forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/projserv2010setup/thread/9b38f908-c75b-465f-80cc-93f4fc5bd72e/)

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Please explain in details.
Is step 2 means Project server service application-> Create Project Web App Site?
and what is permissions in step 3?
and administration group = domain admin?

Comment: Did you tried above steps already and also looked at link I provided and it didn't helped :) ?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't work, or I didn't understand its point.
_I need more details_

Comment: Can you add details about deployment steps you followed.

Comment: Ms Win server 2008 x64 + VMWare + sql2008 all in one server
Installed sharepoint 2010 and Ms Project Server based on microsofts steps. 
at creating PWA step, it goes until provisioning without any problem. But in provisioning database it doesn't stop.